# Writing proofs with modular arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, modular-arithmetic

I am enrolled in Discrete Mathematics 2 and I am having trouble understand a lot of the material. For the particular problems I need help with I need to:

Prove each of the given statements, assuming that
$a,b,c,d$, and $n$ are integers with $n>1$ and that $a\equiv c\bmod n$
and $b\equiv d\bmod n$.

These are the statements:

> 1. a. $a+b\equiv c+d\bmod n$
>      b. $a-b\equiv c-d\bmod n$
> 2. $a^2\equiv c^2\bmod n$
> 3. $a^m\equiv c^m\bmod n$ for all integers $m\ge1$ (Use mathematical
>      induction on $m$).

I am in pretty bad shape as far as approaching and completing these problems and I need this to be explained to me as simply as possible (as if I am a 3 year old). Thank you all for your help in advanced.

Comment: What does it mean for two numbers to be congruent mod n?

Comment: $a \equiv b \pmod{n} \iff n \,\vert\ \, (a-b)$

Comment: https://www.ethz.ch/en/news-and-events/eth-news/news/2018/08/fields-medal-for-figalli.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the first one for you. The same logic follows for the rest. $a\equiv c \pmod n$ means $a=c+mn$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and similarly for $b=d$ mod$n$. So $(c+d)=(a+m_1n)+(b+m_2n)=(a+b)+(m_1+m_2)n\equiv(a+b) \pmod n$